# Undefine PACKAGE_VERSION when using autoconf

Tags: gcc, autotools, automake

I have a project that uses a define called PACKAGE_VERSION for some validations.

When I created a makefile using autoconf, I discovered that for every compile, autconf added a -DPACKAGE_VERSION=1.2 (because that is the version I am using in AC_INIT)

That define is in conflict with de define that my application uses. How can I prevent autoconf for doing this? I tried using AM_SUBST_NOTMAKE(PACKAGE_VERSION) but there was no change.

I don't want to refactor the application changing the name of the constant, I just want autoconf not to add a define that I do not need.

I am new to this autotools, so maybe this is a newbie question. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an unfortunate collision - you could try adding `CFLAGS=-UPACKAGE_VERSION` to your command line to undefine it.

Using `AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])` (explanation [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.64/html_node/Configuration-Headers.html)) will prevent the `-D` flags from being passed to the compiler; then, in the files where you don't want the defines, simply don't `#include "config.h"`.

Ultimately, though, if you plan to continue using Autotools for your package, it would be better to refactor the existing define, because keeping it is likely to cause hard-to-track-down errors down the line.